# Como não escrever o cabeçalho em um CSV toda vez que atualizar o arquivo

Tags: python, csv

Quando crio um arquivo CSV com cabeçalho, todas as vezes que tento inserir novos itens o cabeçalho se repete.

```
# Escrevendo o arquivo
with open('Gerador.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as gravar:
    fieldnames = ['Instituição', 'Senha']
    escrever = csv.DictWriter(gravar, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    escrever.writeheader()

    nome = input('Instituição: ')
    senha = input('Senha: ')

    escrever.writerow({'Instituição': nome, 'Senha': senha})
```

Comment: Você executa a linha `escrever.writeheader()` toda vez que escreve no arquivo. Se quer escrever apenas uma vez, precisa ver para executar essa linha apenas quando cria o arquivo.

Answer (score 3):

Uma ideia é verificar se o arquivo já existia (antes de abri-lo, já que ao abrir com a opção `a`, ele será criado). Aí você só escreve o header se ele não existia:

```
nome_arquivo = 'Gerador.csv'

# verifica se o arquivo existe

# Python >= 3.4
from pathlib import Path
arquivo_ja_existia = Path(nome_arquivo).is_file()

# Ou, para Python < 3.4
import os.path
arquivo_ja_existia = os.path.isfile(nome_arquivo)

import csv
# Escrevendo o arquivo
with open(nome_arquivo, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as gravar:
    fieldnames = ['Instituição', 'Senha']
    escrever = csv.DictWriter(gravar, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if not arquivo_ja_existia: # só escreve o header se o arquivo não existia antes
        escrever.writeheader()
   
    nome = input('Instituição: ')
    senha = input('Senha: ')
    escrever.writerow({'Instituição': nome, 'Senha': senha})
```

Para verificar se o arquivo já existe, coloquei duas opções:

1. para Python >= 3.4 pode ser usado o [módulo `pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)
2. para versões anteriores à 3.4 pode ser usado o [módulo `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)

A seguir, você só escreve o header se o arquivo não existia.

---

Outra opção é verificar a posição do arquivo em que estamos. Se o arquivo for novo, ele estará na posição zero, e somente neste caso eu escrevo o header:

```
import csv
# Escrevendo o arquivo
with open(nome_arquivo, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as gravar:
    fieldnames = ['Instituição', 'Senha']
    escrever = csv.DictWriter(gravar, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if gravar.tell() == 0: # só escreve o header se estiver no início do arquivo
        escrever.writeheader()
   
    nome = input('Instituição: ')
    senha = input('Senha: ')
    escrever.writerow({'Instituição': nome, 'Senha': senha})
```

Comment: Bem que o objeto `gravar` podia ter uma flag indicando se o arquivo é novo ou não xD